# How can i call mutliple webservices provided by different vendors with same input in java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am new to websevices. My requirement is to call different webservices that are provided by different vendors with the same input in a java class. For example: weather information is provided by different vendors and all vendors are taking input as a city name. I want to call a method in a java class which calls all webservices in parallel provided by different vendors. Then I have to show the results in jsp by vendor (all vendors using axis2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be difficult if you are having the same input.

Assuming you are using the axis2 Java API, you can do something like:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AxisFault,Exception {

        RPCServiceClient serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();
        Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();

        String [] vendors = {"http://example.com/vendor1/services/GETWeatherHttpSoap12Endpoint", "http://example.com/vendor2/services/GETWeatherHttpSoap12Endpoint"}; // Array of all vendors

        for (String vendor : vendors) {
            EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(vendor);
            options.setTo(targetEPR);
            QName opGetExchange = new QName("http://ws.apache.org/axis2", "getWeather");

            // preparing the parameters
            String country = "USA";
            Object[] opGetExchangeArgs = new Object[] {country};

            // preparing the return type
            Class[] returnTypes = new Class[] { String.class };

            // invoking the service passing in the arguments and getting the response
            Object[] response = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(opGetExchange, opGetExchangeArgs, returnTypes);
            // obtaining the data from the response
            String result = (String) response[0];

            System.out.println("Vendor: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out the result from each vendor on a different line.

Comment: Hi if one of webservice is fails is there any  affect on result? i mean rest of result will display or total request will fail? can we use timeout when calling different a methods provided by different vendors..so if it take time then we can display other results?

Comment: yes. if one webservice fails it will throw an exception. you will have to catch the exception specifically for the vendor and then perhaps display an error message. if you want to increase the speed, you can consider running them in parallel using threads, then commit the results to a common endpoint